# How Can i subset in pandas by multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

ex:

```
Cat INVOICE_REF_NUMBER  OPEN_ITEM_AMOUNT(Netted Amt)    AMOUNT_ COLLECTED(Original Amt) COMPANY_CODE    OPERATING_UNIT count
invoice 0992541158  115606.38   578031.91   4380    6238   2
payment 0992541158  0          -462425.53   4380    6238   2
invoice 0090010917  1519         87803.4    2700    4315   2
payment 0090010917  0           -86284.4    2700    4315   2
invoice 0090007022  2039.55      13517      2700    4315   2
```

i need separate 5th line as it doesnt had any payment, 
 -

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I done it in excel by doing countifs based on "cat" and took if any key has only both invoice & payment, so needs to implement in python

Comment: You might need to explain what you'd like to do. But you can always do something like this `df2=df1[df1['Column_Name'] == 'Condition']`. for multiple conditions you should use the `~` for NOT `|` for OR and `&` for and

Answer (score 0):

Start by grouping all lines that are related to the same invoice. There combined status will be different based on whether the invoice has been payed or not:

```
status = df.groupby("INVOICE_REF_NUMBER")['Cat'].sum()
#INVOICE_REF_NUMBER
#0090007022           invoice
#0090010917    invoicepayment
#0992541158    invoicepayment
#Name: Cat, dtype: object
```

Now, extract the original lines with unpayed invoices:

```
unpayed = df.join(status[status=='invoice'], rsuffix='_', how='right', 
                  on='INVOICE_REF_NUMBER')
#       Cat INVOICE_REF_NUMBER  OPEN_ITEM_AMOUNT(Netted Amt)     Cat_
#4  invoice         0090007022                       2039.55  invoice
```

You can remove the duplicate 'Cat_' column, if you want:

```
del unpayed['Cat_']
#       Cat INVOICE_REF_NUMBER  OPEN_ITEM_AMOUNT(Netted Amt)
#4  invoice         0090007022                       2039.55
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best effort:

```
# Assume nothing has a payment
df['payment_count'] = 0

# For each invoice, count the related payments by applying
# a lambda function on each row (hence the axis=1)
df.loc[df.Cat=='invoice', 'payment_count'] =     
    df.loc[df.Cat=='invoice'].apply(lambda x: \      
    df.loc[(df['INVOICE_REF_NUMBER']==x['INVOICE_REF_NUMBER']) \
    & df.Cat=='payment')], 'Cat').count(), axis=1)

# Filter on the invoices without payments
print((df[df.Cat=='invoice') & (df.payment_count==0)])
```